# eclipse plugin: get notification on debug terminate

Tags: debugging, eclipse-plugin

Is there a way for an eclipse plugin to get a notification when user clicks on the "Terminate Debug" button?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call

```java
DebugPlugin.getDefault().addDebugEventListener(listener);
```

to set up an `IDebugEventSetListener`. The `DebugEvent` passed to the `handleDebugEvents` method of the listener has `TERMINATE` as one of the event kinds.

For example this handler is from the Ant plugin:

```java
@Override
public void handleDebugEvents(DebugEvent[] events) {
    for (int i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
        DebugEvent event = events[i];
        if (event.getKind() == DebugEvent.TERMINATE && event.getSource().equals(fProcess)) {
            terminated();
        }
    }
}
```