# How to perform an action on the event of terminate(red button) in eclipse console?

Tags: javascript, java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am running a thread program using Java in eclipse.
I want to get the event of Red button click(Program Terminate) to find the stopping time of program.
How do I do that?
Note: [Handle the click on the Terminate button of an Eclipse's console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183227/handle-the-click-on-the-terminate-button-of-an-eclipses-console)
This is a similar question. But the answers in it does not answer the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Handle the click on the Terminate button of an Eclipse's console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21183227/handle-the-click-on-the-terminate-button-of-an-eclipses-console)

Comment: The Red button terminates the program immediately, there is nothing the program can do to deal with this.

Comment: @thokuest that does not answer my question properly. Please check the answers in that link.

Comment: @greg-449 even though the programs is stopped immediately, there should be an event that is attached to the same. Just need the event and then we can perform an action on in right?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. The program itself cannot deal with this. An Eclipse plug-in can probably use the debug APIs to listen for the terminate event.

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30148053/2670892) for details of listening in an Eclipse plug-in